# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' when using Axios to fetch data from an API in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, object, axios

when getting req from API .. res => this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K3q5.png)

when added to my project like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1LPF.png)

send me this error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPF3Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f02Xc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrV1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're getting the response in a variable called `res`:

```
let res = {
  "prices" : {
    "BTC/USDT" : 27071.28
  },
  "ms" : 3
}
```

Then to get BTC/USDT prices you can use: `res["prices"]["BTC/USDT"]`

So [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f02Xc.png) at line 40 you can use `const req = '${btcToUsd}["BTC/USDT"]'`

Comment: `res.["prices"].["BTC/USDT"]` is clearly a syntax error.

Comment: Added the . by mistake it should be res["prices"]["BTC/USDT"]

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the object key correctly. Given that you have a slash in the object key, you will need to do something like this: `responseObject.prices[“BTC/USDT”]`.

If I were you, I would update the name of the key to something like `btc_usdt`, so that way you could access the object like this: `responseObject.prices.btc_usdt`.